# Retrieving photo likes through Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to store information about photos of Facebook pages.

I use for example this call to the graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/328548953909061/albums?fields=count,id,name,cover_photo,type,photos{id,name,created_time,picture,source,link,likes}&$acces_token

Since a couple of weeks I get this error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

When I remove ",likes" from the url it works. Anyone knows what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your initial call you need add v2.1

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/328548953909061/albums?...
```

Additionally I would call the following.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/328548953909061/albums?fields=count,id,cover_photo,type,photos{id,name,created_time,picture,source,link,likes.summary(true).filter(stream)}&access_token=...
```

Adding .summary(true) and .filter(stream) to the likes field will give you a Summary doc in the photo doc and Filter will force all the nodes in to the count. Facebook "hides" some nodes of low "Top Story" value.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this works fine in the API explorer [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=cafereuring%2Falbums%3Ffields%3Did%2Ccover_photo%2Ctype%2Cphotos%7Bid%2Cname%2Ccreated_time%2Cpicture%2Csource%2Clink%2Clikes.summary(true).limit(0)%7D&version=v2.1) but when I want to make this call using an access token generated for my app I get the error again. Any suggestions?

Comment: So in my original post I made a couple errors in the second suggested http call. I have edited it. I missed a "?" in the http call between albums and fields, and I miss spelled Token, and forgot the "_". Also make sure your access token has not expired.